# Python tkinter get() from another function

Tags: python, tkinter, get, tkinter-entry

```
def CreateGUI():
    WinCreate=Toplevel(master)
    WinCreate.attributes("-toolwindow",1)
    WinCreate.resizable(0,0)
    WinCreate.transient(master)
    WinCreate.grab_set()
    sideframe=Frame(WinCreate,bd=2,relief=GROOVE)
    Label(WinCreate,text="                        logbook                         ",fg="White",bg="#3b5998",font=("RoyalBavarian",20)).pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
    Label(sideframe,text="Name: ",fg="Black",font=("Tahoma",12)).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
    Label(sideframe,text="Age: ",fg="Black",font=("Tahoma",12)).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E)
    Label(sideframe,text="Gender: ",fg="Black",font=("Tahoma",12)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=E)
    Label(sideframe,text="Eye Color: ",fg="Black",font=("Tahoma",12)).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=E)
    txtName=Entry(sideframe)
    txtAge=Entry(sideframe)
    txtEye=Entry(sideframe)
    txtName.grid(row=0,column=1)
    txtAge.grid(row=1,column=1)
    var=StringVar(sideframe)
    var.set("Male")
    optGender=OptionMenu(sideframe,var,"Male","Female")
    optGender.grid(row=2,column=1)
    txtEye.grid(row=3,column=1)
    sideframe.pack(side=LEFT,pady=7,padx=7,ipady=3,ipadx=3)
    rightside=Frame(WinCreate,height=116,width=283)
    irighttop=Frame(rightside,bd=2,relief=GROOVE)
    irightbottom=Frame(rightside,bd=2,width=274,height=50,relief=GROOVE)
    Label(irighttop,text="Username: ",fg="Black",font=("Tahoma",12)).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
    Label(irighttop,text="Password: ",fg="Black",font=("Tahoma",12)).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E)
    Label(irighttop,text="Confirm Password: ",fg="Black",font=("Tahoma",12)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=E)
    txtUsername=Entry(irighttop)
    txtPassword=Entry(irighttop)
    txtConPass=Entry(irighttop)
    txtUsername.grid(row=0,column=1)
    txtPassword.grid(row=1,column=1)
    txtConPass.grid(row=2,column=1)
    irighttop.pack(side=TOP,ipady=3,ipadx=3)
    btnCreateFinal=Button(irightbottom,text="Create",fg="Black",command=Create(txtName,txtAge,txtEye,var,txtPassword,txtConPass,txtUsername))
    btnCancel=Button(irightbottom,text="Cancel",fg="Black")
    btnCreateFinal.pack(side=LEFT)
    btnCancel.pack(side=RIGHT)
    irightbottom.pack_propagate(0)
    irightbottom.pack(side=BOTTOM,ipady=3,ipadx=3)
    rightside.pack_propagate(0)
    rightside.pack(side=RIGHT)
def Create(txtName,txtAge,txtEye,var,txtPassword,txtConPass,txtUsername):
    choice='1'
    password="blank"
    conpassword="blank2"
    #----------------------
    name=txtName.get()
    age=txtAge.get()
    gender=var.get()
    eye=txtEye.get()
    password=txtPassword.get()
    conpassword=txtConPass.get()
```

My question here is how can I get data from the entry boxes if they are in another function? All the entry boxes are in CreateGUI() function. I thought to pass the variables txtName etc to the Create() function. Is this method correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GUI programming is usually done inside a class:

```
class SimpleApp(object):
    def createGUI(self):
        ...
        self.txtName=Entry(sideframe)
        self.txtName.grid(row=0,column=1)

    def create(self):
        ...
        name=self.txtName.get()
```

By making `txtName` an attribute of `self`, you can access its value in other methods with `self.txtName`. The other variables can be handled the same way.

Comment: thanks! I'll try this out. I am going to read Class documentation first

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to give your Entry widgets a StringVar instance to store input.

```
  self.myStringVar = tk.StringVar()
  self.myEntryWidget = tk.Entry(self.myFrame,textvariable=self.myStringVar)
  self.myEntryWidget.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Then in some other function you call:

```
  self.myStringVar.get()
```

This is all better off inside a class as it makes the GUI much easier to manage.

Comment: "need" is a rather strong word. Using a variable isn't the only solution to this problem.